# How can I remove the axes from an Oxplot graph but retain zoom and pan functionality?

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I can remove axes using `IsAxisVisible = false` like the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683644/oxyplot-how-to-remove-axes), but when I do so can no longer pan or zoom the graph.

Example code where the graph doesn't pan (using Oxyplot 2.0):

```
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            var tmp = new PlotModel { Title = "Simple example", Subtitle = "using OxyPlot" };

            tmp.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                IsAxisVisible = false
            });

            tmp.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Left,
                IsAxisVisible = false
            });

            var series1 = new LineSeries { Title = "Series 1", MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle };
            series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 0));
            series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 18));
            series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(20, 12));
            series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(30, 8));
            series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(40, 15));

            tmp.Series.Add(series1);

            this.Model = tmp;
        }
        public PlotModel Model { get; private set; }
    }
```

Edit:

**xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf" 
        xmlns:simpleDemo="clr-namespace:SimpleDemo"
        Title="OxyPlot SimpleDemo" Height="480" Width="640">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <simpleDemo:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
   }
```

Comment: @AnuViswan I can confirm that zooming in doesn't work. Also running the above code with the `IsAxisVisible = false` lines removed allows you to pan at any level of zoom.

Comment: Ah ok, good to know it might be something simple! Added Xaml code above.

Comment: Out of curiosity,  don't see series2 definition.

Comment: I simplified some demo code to make the example but missed that reference. Same behaviour with it removed unfortunately.

Comment: What's the version of OxyPlot you are using ? 2.0 ? Looks like something has changed from 1.0 to 2.0. Could you please downgrade your oxyplot version to 1.0 and check

Comment: You are right, changing to version 1.0 resolves the zoom issue. Unfortunately the downgrade breaks some other features I've implemented though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've settled on (at least until the `IsAxisVisible = false` issue described in the original question is fixed) is to implement Anu's answer, with the addition of:

```
Model.PlotMargins = new OxyThickness(0);
```

To hide the axis thickness.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comment earlier, this behavior seems to be happening with Oxyplot 2.0, while 1.0 does allow Zoom/Pan even when the Axis is invisible.

An alternative approach would be to set the `AxislineColor`,`TextColor`,and `TicklineColor` to `OxyColors.Transparent`.

```
tmp.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
    IsZoomEnabled = true,
    IsPanEnabled = true,
    AxislineColor = OxyColors.Transparent,
    TextColor = OxyColors.Transparent,
    TicklineColor = OxyColors.Transparent
}); ; ;

tmp.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Left,
    IsZoomEnabled = true,
    IsPanEnabled = true,
    AxislineColor = OxyColors.Transparent,
    TextColor = OxyColors.Transparent,
    TicklineColor = OxyColors.Transparent
});
```

This would allow you to Zoom/Pan without displaying the Axis.

Comment: Thanks Anu. I had tried this but couldn't find a way to remove the space taken up by the invisible axis-do you know if this is possible?